# PowerShell idiom to test for existence of a command?

Tags: powershell, idioms

I'd like a function to test for the existence of a command (cmdlet, function, alias, etc.) in PowerShell.  It should behave like this:

```
PS C:\> Test-Command ls
True
PS C:\> Test-Command lss
False
```

I have a function that works but strikes me as neither idiomatic nor elegant.  Is there a more *posh* way to do this:

```
function Test-Command( [string] $CommandName )
{
    $ret = $false
    try
    {
        $ret = @(Get-Command $CommandName -ErrorAction Stop).length -gt 0
    }
    catch
    {
        # do nothing
    }
    return $ret
}
```

Bonus question:

Python : *pythonic* :: PowerShell : *?*

I'd say *posh* but is there something else in common use?

Comment: I think that saying the idiomatic way to do things in PowerShell is the "posh way" is just too good.  Definitely using that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
function Test-Command( [string] $CommandName )
{
    (Get-Command $CommandName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null
}
```

(BTW, I like *posh* )

Comment: The argument should probably be names `$CommandName` to conform to usual practices for naming command parameters (will be particular apparent if doing tab-expansion on it).

Answer (score 1):

for the bonus question i say "PowerShelly"